# creating a fstream object from memory buffer

Tags: c++, c, file, memory, buffer

Suppose I have some memory allocated by malloc. Now i want to use it as stream buffer as fstream object. In another situation suppose i've a FILE*. Is it possible to create a fstream object from it?

---

Actually I've an existing library which accepts FILE* arguments in it's function.Now I want to implement the library with cpp type file handling, maintaining backward compatability . What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not make a `fstream` object from a `FILE*`.

You should personally write a stream based on C++ standard I/O streams which works by a `FILE*`

Comment: I thought about a custom class inheriting from iostream.But I wanted to ask isn't there anything easier?

Comment: I think the easier way is searching for third-party class library or look in boost, Qt, Poco, ... to find a streaming system which accepts `FILE*`